# Checking whether ruby script is running in windows

Tags: ruby

I need to run a ruby script for one week and check whether it is running for every hour.
Could you please suggest me some way? I need to check this in windows machine.

For ex:- I have script called one_week_script.rb which will run for one week, in between i want to check whether the script is running or not? if it is not running, then running that script from another script

Answer (score 1):

A typical solution is to use a "heartbeat" strategy.  The "to be monitored" notifies a "watchdog" process on a regular interval.  A simple way of doing this might be to update the contents of some file every so often, and the watchdog simply checks that same file to see if it's got recent data.

The alternative, simply checking if the process is still 'loaded' has some weaknesses, The program could be locked up, even though it's still apparently 'running'.  Using the heartbeat/watchdog style means you know that the watched process is operating normally, because you're getting feedback from it.

In a typical scenario, you might just write the current time, and some arbitrary diagnostic data, say the number of bytes processed (whatever that might mean for you).